# ControlClick() without control ID

Tags: autoit

My AutoIt script simulates mouse clicks. First a right click in one place, then a left click in one of many other points. I achieved that with `MouseClick()` and it works fine.

But now I want the script to work in "background" so I used `ControlClick()`. But there's no control ID. This is what I tried:

```
$square = Floor(Random(0,$length)) ;this one gets length of array with coordinates

;MouseClick("right", 1634,195 ,1,1) first version-works fine
ControlClick("Medivia","", "", "right",1,1634,195)

;MouseClick("left", $cordX[$square], $cordY[$square]) first version-works fine
ControlClick("Medivia","", "", "left",1 ,$cordX[$square] ,$cordY[$square])
```

The script clicks, but only in the place where I leave the mouse pointer.  It does not move the mouse pointer by itself. Could anybody help me?

Comment: ControlClick needs a Control to click - thats why the name. If you don't have a control to click, this function is not usefull.

Comment: Not true, without a specified control AutoIt is effectively treating the entire window as a control, e.g. http://brugbart.com/click-minimized-windows-autoit I've tested it myself with Firefox minimized and it works. The mouse cursor doesn't move, so that's normal. Try using WinGetHandle() to verify that AutoIt can get a handle to the window.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I use Control... functions a lot without a ControlID parameter.

Answer (score 1):

***Answer Limitation***: **To use any of the `Control*` APIs from AutoIT, you're going to need to be interacting with a *real* Windows control.**

If you just want to do "random" clicks, you probably don't need a real Windows control and should not be relying on `ControlClick`.

If you're trying to click on the "background" of Windows, you probably want to just minimize all open windows, which you can accomplish with `WinMinimizeAll`.

#### GUI clicks with Qt and other frameworks without real Windows Controls

Some frameworks like Qt will not give you a real Windows control for many of the default GUI buttons and the like, so when using AutoIT's Windows Info tool, as well as many of the UI spy tools out there, that info will be missing.

What you may need and I currently need is to resort are workarounds. For your case, it would help if I could see a screenshot of the sequence you're trying to automate; I could give better advice after seeing that.

For my case, I needed to click on a `Quit` button that had no controls and the developer told me he didn't have a way (or know a way) to add accessible names to the pop-up I was trying to hook into, even though I could hook to the main app's hWND. Luckily, that quit-box had a special color for the Quit button, which allowed me to use AutoIT's `PixelSearch` to locate it.

When you don't have cool helpers like that, it's usually best to determine the location of the main window, and whatever pixel-offset you need to find what you're looking for.